# SonarLint missing Java Rule on VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sonarqube, sonarlint, linter

I have installed [SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode), [SonarQube support for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=silverbulleters.sonarqube-inject), and also [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/).

Here is my global.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silverbulleters/sonarqube-inject-vsc/master/schemas/global.json",
    "servers": [
        {
            "id": "localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9000/",
            "token": "28636f8b1a718c765b827d32bcafb7df3e44930b"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my local sonarlint.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silverbulleters/sonarqube-inject-vsc/master/schemas/sonarlint.json",
    "serverId": "localhost",
    "projectKey": "springmvc"
}
```

Here is my env settings:

1. sonarqube-7.8.
2. java version "1.8.0_201".
3. VSCode version 1.41.1.
4. JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are set.

**Update binding to SonarQube server** is working very well.

[image: a]

Update all Binding to SonarQube/SonarCloud also work perfectly.
[image]

My Question are:

Missing Java Rule on SonarLint sidebar

[image]

1. How to have Java Rules enabled there?
2. What kind tasks VSCode can do together with the SonarQube Server?
3. After all of the installation and configuration I see that nothing is happened?

Linter doesn't work

[image]

Any help regarding this really appreciated.

Comment: As per this link I think Java language rules are not supported right now. SonarLint spots bugs and quality issues as fast as you code.

5 languages supported: C#, VB .Net, C, C++ and Javascript.https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio2019

Comment: ya, it's not supported yet https://community.sonarsource.com/t/the-linter-for-java-rule-doesnt-exist-on-vscode/18383/2

Comment: It's supported now, see the SonarLint's official post: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-can-now-analyze-java-code-in-vscode/21029

Answer (score 0):

Hi already got the answer from the forum that said that Java is not supported yet.

"SonarLint for VSCode doesn’t support Java projects for the time being. You can analyze PHP, Python, JS, TS, HTML out of the box, and a few more languages in connected mode (Apex, PL/SQL, …) but not Java.
We have started some collaboration with VSCode Java developers in order to possibly unlock this feature, so stay tuned."

See:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVSCODE-35

answer source: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/the-linter-for-java-rule-doesnt-exist-on-vscode/18383/2